# Is it not possible to put UISearchBar in UITableView header?

Tags: uisearchbar, reloaddata, uitableview, uisearchbardelegate

I am trying to accomplish this:

> Consider a table view with Search Bar on its header.Table view gets
>   refreshed whenever string is searched.

I am having 2 classes

**TableViewController**(UIViewController subclass)

contains UITableView  -That shows the table whose

> **header view of the table** is loaded from the Header class(UIToolBar subclass)

.

**Header**(header of the UITableView)
-Contains **UISearchBar and its delegate**

The

> UISearchBarDelegates call back a function in TableViewController

that calls

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

which causes App to crash

The **function call stack frame** is as follows

```
[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:]  
[TableViewController functionThatCallsReloadSection]  
[Header searchBarSearchButtonClicked:]
```

The reloadSection is causing the App to crash .Any ideas why its happening so?

> Is it because the delegate function is still active on the stack 
>   while the   the table view header is reloaded??

I am not changing any anything related to the tableview (no change in the number of rows or sections).All i am trying to doing is to just reload the table view.

Edited:
I am trying to do all these things in iPad,which provides a popover while using UISearchDisplayController which i dont want to use.I already have a table view which i want to refresh once the text is entered and search button is hit,using the search delegate.
The only problem is that once i call [UITableView reloadSection:] in the search delegate of UISearchBar(UISearchBar is located on the header of the UITableView  that i want to reload) the app crashes.

Comment: should i implement the search bar as a different toolbar and not as a header of the table view?

Comment: eventhough the app dosent crash if i perform a reloadData instead of the reload section,the app will crash once it encounter a reloadSection for the same table some where in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using the tableViewHeader instead of loadind the table view header using the table view header delegate method where i used a pointer thats initialised to the table view header.